# Odoo 8 POS default field language

Tags: xml, default, odoo-8, point-of-sale

I'd like to set a default value for the country field when creating a customer.
Is it possible to set a default parameter to the language?

```
<div class='client-detail'>
       <span class='label'>Language</span>
       <select class='detail client-partner-lang' name='lang'>

       <t t-foreach='widget.pos.langs' t-as='language'>
              <t t-if='partner.lang == language.code'>
                   <option t-att-value='language.code'> 
                              <t t-esc='language.name'/>
                   </option>
              </t>
       </t>

       <t t-foreach='widget.pos.langs' t-as='language'>
              <option t-att-value='language.code' t-att-selected="partner_language_id ? ((language.code === partner.lang) ? true : undefined) : undefined"> 
                        <t t-esc='language.name'/>
              </option>
       </t>
       </select>
</div>
```